# Integromat Match Pattern - Find the word Fandoms and Provide Associated String

Tags: html, regex, discord, rss, make.com

I am working on an Integromat Scenario where I am attempting to aggregate RSS feeds into one feed that will post to a discord server. The feeds have a "Description" that I have to split up into HTML links using the "Get Elements from HTML" Text Parser in Integromat. This returns the following:

Integromat Post

[image]

See how it's pulling each of the five links in the description and their associated text into five different posts. I need to only return the the second link as the whole post and none of the others.

Or, use RegEx to pull out the "Fandoms" portion of the HTML to achieve a similar result. The original HTML from the Feed that is being parsed looks like this:

Raw RSS HTML

[image]

So far, I have tried multiple RegEx, but cannot achieve a single post in Integromat with the Title, Author, and Fandom. I simply cannot pull the Fandom portion out of the Feed Description without help.

Integromat support will not help. They would have me pay a third party to explain their product or write the scenario for me. This isn't a business or a for-profit. This is a fun discord server, a community of people who are trying to say connected. And we don't have a lot of money.

I'm not a programmer.

Anyone willing to assist, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Can you share me the plain text RSS feed?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a regex guy and there might be a better solution than what I am purposing.

The first thing that you will need is to set up a regex module that will extract the `<li>` element with the text `Fandoms` on it.

```
\<li\>[^<]*?(Fandoms).*?\<\/li\>
```

You can see a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/PFP3CD/1).

After that, You will need to modules in Integromat that will Parse the RSS feed with the given regex first to extract the HTML element. Which can be done by using the regex expression,

```
(?<result><li\>[^<]*?(Fandoms).*?\<\/li\>.*)
```

What this will do is group the result as `result` variable in Integromat that can then be used for further processing.

[image]

After doing this, you can now use Text Parse Module to again extract anchor link for further processing,

[image]

And, The result will look something like this,

[image]